# How to resolve a path in a non controller class in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a form builder class which inherits from `AbstractType` and I need to resolve a path like this:

```
$uri = $router->generate('blog_show', array('slug' => 'my-blog-post'));
```

Since the class is not a child of `Controller` I have no access to the router. Any ideas?

What about passing the router to the class on construction time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass the `router` service via constructor to your form type. Register your form as a service with the `form.type` tag and inject the `router` service to it.

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Bundle\AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var Router
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @param Router
     */
    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'post';
    }

    // ...
}
```

Register it as a service:

```
services:
    form.type.post:
        class: Vendor\Bundle\AppBundle\Form\Type\PostType
        arguments: [ @router ]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

And use it in your controller like this:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();
    $form = $this->createForm('post', $post);

    // ...
}
```

Since you registered your form type as a service with the `form.type` tag, you can simply use its name instead of `new PostType()`. And you can access the `router` service as `$this->router` in your type.

Comment: Can you specify the php template version code for `arguments: [ @router ]`?

Comment: See the PHP tab in [this section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services).

Answer (score 1):

If you going to use your form builder class in some controller, you can do it more simpler and your form builder going more flexible:

```
public function someAction() {
    //...

    $task = new Task();
    $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('target_route'),
        'method' => 'GET',
    ));
}
```

There is no need to set the URL in the form type class.
Read more here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html

Answer (score 0):

You can define this class as a service and inject router service into it.

More info: [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).