# Symfony2 - Generate route in custom form type and extend DoctrineType

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I am using Symfony 2.2 and I want to generate the url in buildView method by usign the folowing code:

**$this->router>generateUrl($options['ajaxRoute']);** but I can't because it extends DoctrineType and I don't have the router.

```
namespace MyBundle\Test;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\DoctrineType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class EntityAjaxType extends DoctrineType 
    {

        public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
        {
            parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);

            $view->vars['ajaxRoute'] = $options['ajaxRoute'];
            $view->vars['ajaxFilters'] = json_encode(empty($options['ajaxFilters']) ? array() : $options['ajaxFilters']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9871934/3133441